# Multiple servers (in different locations) with single domain

Tags: linux, ssh, dns, dynamic-dns

I have a VPS located in another part of the world that has a static IP. I also have a server at home which has a dynamic IP.

Right now, I'm using No-IP's dynamic DNS client to update my home server's IP and keep it linked to my domain. I was wondering if I could somehow, at the same time, point a particular subdomain to my VPS instead of my home server?

In other words, www.mydomain.com is hosted on my home server while www.mydomain.com/subdomain is hosted on my VPS (or vice versa). Thing is, I have to ssh to my VPS quite often too so it has to be more than just a normal URL redirection.

Both servers are linux based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name `www.mydomain.com/subdomain` is not a subdomain. It is just a subfolder. A subdomain will be `sub.mydomain.com`. A new DNS record `A` record can be created for this subdomain and it can be pointed to a different server.

Comment: Ah... I see. Thanks. As for the DNS record A record, where would I do the configuration? With my domain registrar (i.e. No-IP.com)?